# How do I configure a NSButtonCell by code?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How do I configure a NSButtonCell by code ? I couldn't find any example or help in the documentation.

So far I've this:

```
   cell = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
   [tableColumn setDataCell:cell];
```

1. How do I specify I want a check box button?
2. How do I bind it to the datasource?

thanks

UPDATE: (the button is not enabled yet)

```
            [bindingOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSConditionallySetsEditableBindingOption];
            [bindingOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSConditionallySetsEnabledBindingOption];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps somewhat confusingly, in an `NSTableView`, the bindings happen at the `NSTableColumn` level, not the `NSCell` level. So you would call `- (void)bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` on the `tableColumn` with probably with something like:

```
[tableColumn bind: NSValueBinding toObject: theViewController withKeyPath: @"representedObject.foo.bar" options: @{ ... }];
```

As for making the cell look like a checkbox, you want to do this:

```
[cell setButtonType: NSSwitchButton];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks: one last question: the button is not clickable, it is disabled. The binding works, but I can't interact with it.

Comment: That could be any number of things... you might want to try twiddling the `NSConditionallySetsEditableBindingOption` or `NSConditionallySetsEnabledBindingOption` when you bind the tableColumn. These would be passed in (with values) via the `options:` dictionary parameter.

Comment: I've added to my question the lines I've added, it is still the same

Comment: Hard to say without being able to debug it myself... sorry.  My recommendation would be to set up a table, using only IB, that works the way you want your dynamically configured table to work in this case, and then look in the debugger at how the columns are bound (i.e. with what options) `-infoForBinding:` is your friend in this regard.

Comment: Sorry, it actually work already. I don't know why it was disabled before, I've removed all binding options, and it is ok.

Comment: Just, I've one last problem, when I click on the switch, the value doesn't change, it remains the same. But I can see the button is actually clicked.

Comment: Again, hard to say without being able to see it.

Comment: NSButtonCells are also dimmed if the binding cannot be resolved. I've found the bindings can fail silently, even if NSRaisesForNotApplicableKeysBindingOption is true.